# Parallel processing and order of execution with recursive loop

Tags: powershell, parallel-processing, recursive

If i run a script that **processes a path recursively using parallel processing** to execute a command on the whole tree if items, am I **guaranteed** that the commands I use will be executed on all items in a single directory **before stepping to the next one**?

```
Get-ChildItem $Path -Recurse -Filter *.some_file_extension | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    my_command $_ --with_options
}
```

Comment: You really want to read up on the meaning of parallel processing in general (since it is not anything unique to PowerShell - which only got it in later versions), to set your expectations. ['PowerShell parallel processing'](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+parallel+processing%27&t=h_&ia=web).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the MS Docs on regarding the feature and use case:

> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-foreach-object-parallel-feature
>
> Normally, when you use the ForEach-Object cmdlet, each object piped to
> the cmdlet is processed sequentially.

```
1..5 | 
ForEach-Object { "Hello $_"; sleep 1 }

Hello 1
Hello 2
Hello 3
Hello 4
Hello 5

(Measure-Command {
    1..5 | ForEach-Object { "Hello $_"; sleep 1 } 
}).Seconds
5
```

> ***But with the new ForEach-Object -Parallel parameter set, you can ***run all script in parallel*** for each piped input object.***

```
1..5 | 
ForEach-Object -Parallel { "Hello $_"; sleep 1; } -ThrottleLimit 5
 
Hello 1 
Hello 3 
Hello 2 
Hello 4 
Hello 5 

(Measure-Command {
    1..5 | 
ForEach-Object -Parallel { "Hello $_"; sleep 1; } -ThrottleLimit 5 
}).Seconds
1
```

> Because each script block in the ForEach-Object example above takes 1
> second to run, running all five in parallel takes only one second
> instead of 5 seconds when run sequentially.
>
> ***Since the script blocks are run in parallel for each of the 1-5 piped
> input integers, the order of execution is not guaranteed.*** The
> -ThrottleLimit parameter limits the number of script blocks running in parallel at a given time, and its default value is 5.

Comment: I understand that the files are processed in parallel aka "at the same time (as far as the buffer can take items"). I know I could iterate over the folders sequentially and than feed the items to a loop marked as parallel. I'm still not 100% sure that the files would be processed in order of appearance in the directory tree (even if that means that would be a slight disconnect in which file is processing and which has finished processing). But you're right parallel processing is just that, I can just iterate sequentially over the folders if I'm still in doubt...

Comment: [Or look at parallel processing in combination with workflows](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27PowerShell+parrallel+processing+workflow%27&t=h_&ia=web). Though workflow has been, well, problematic. Meaning, never really worked as intended for those who did try.